# Spring Suite Tool New Project Template Not Loading

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Im Thilina and Im new to spring tool suite. My Operating system is windows 8.

- I first extracted  "spring-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e4.2-win32-x86_64.zip"file.
- Next I i went to the "springsource" folder and selected "sts-3.1.0.RELEASE" folder.
- I double  clicked STS.exe to execute Spring Tool Suite.
- Next  In the dashboard I click Create > Spring Template Project.
- Then I get the following error  "Error while downloading or parsing descriptors file    'https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-templates/master/si-sts-templates/builds/descriptor.xml':

  org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error while retrieving  https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-"
- My internet is working fine. I don't know why I'm getting this problem. 
  Hope you guys can help me to solve this issue.

Appreciate your time and effort.

Thank you.

---

Regards,

---

Thilina Gunawardane

Comment: you may need to allow STS to access internet. Antivirus programs may be preventing it from that.

Comment: Hi Subin, Thank you for the feedback, I use kaspersky2013 antivirus.After seeing your comment i checked my antivirus program, it mentioned "Low Restricted"  in front of STS.exe. Then what I did was, I changed that status to "Trusted". But it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?133139-Spring-Suite-Tool-New-Project-Template-Not-Loading

Here's questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-679

For complete fix read the blog entry below

http://nomsdom.blogspot.in/2012/12/spring-suite-tool-new-project-template.html

Comment: Instead of providing links, you could explain something more about the article, because links expire,
 you see?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this in another way. I assume that this cause due to the certification of SSL(Secured Socket Layer). So I just removed the "links" which uses SSL, then I could see the Spring MVC project. There were only two templates you can see using this method. Although this won't work for you, you can easily restore the default setting by pushing the "Restore Default". Make sure check the 'Show self-hosted templates in New Templates Wizard", so that you can see hidden URL and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of version compatibility.If you are using Spring tool suit of latest version and using jdk of lower version then it will create problem.Please try jdk7 for latest spring tool suit.